# Active navbar link background color sticking to its default

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, scrollspy

Have added custom CSS for active li elements of navbar . But they seem to be picking the default black background color. I want to change its background color to #428BCA. Other elements of navbar are changing their colors according to the code.

My CSS code is as follows:

```
carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
height: 850px;
}
body {
position: relative;
}
#section1 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
#section2 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
#section3 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
#section41 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
#section42 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
.navbar {
position:fixed;
top:0;
z-index:10;
width:100%;
background-color:black;
opacity: 0.9;
}
#nav-right>.active{
background-image:none;
background-color: #428BCA;
color: white;
}
#nav-right>.active>li>a, #nav-right>.active>li>a:hover, #nav-right>.active>li>a :focus{
background-image:none;
background-color: #428BCA;
color: white;
}
#nav-right li a {
color: #428BCA;
}
#nav-right li a:hover{
background-color: #428BCA;
color: white;
}
#drop-menu > .active > a, #drop-menu > .active > a:hover, #drop-menu> .active > a:focus {
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #17AA76, #149466);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
#drop-menu li a:hover {
background-image:none;
background-color:#16A170;
}
#drop-menu li a{
background-image:none;
color: black;
}
```

I am posting the fiddle to exactly state my problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/mukundm/d0Lhvc1z/24/

Please help me with this.

Comment: Try this .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a{background:#428BCA !important}

Comment: i can see :#428BCA as their background..can you give a correct snapshot of what your trying exactly

Comment: @Nandhu, I tried this, the text color is changing but the background color is not changing. I am sorry I accidentally wrote color instead of background color.... Thanks for the advice by the way  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should give the css background property to the `#nav-right > .active > a` instead of `#nav--right > .active` in the css code. This is because bootstrap does not apply background property to the `<li>` element but instead it apllies it to the `<a>` element instead the `<li>` element. And when the link is made active then the active class is added to the `<li>` element. So your css code should be as follows:

```
carousel-inner > .item > img, .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
height: 850px;
}
body {
position: relative;
}
#section1 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #1E88E5;}
#section2 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #673ab7;}
#section3 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #ff9800;}
#section41 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #00bcd4;}
#section42 {padding-top:50px;height:500px;color: #fff; background-color: #009688;}
.navbar {
position:fixed;
top:0;
z-index:10;
width:100%;
background-color:black;
opacity: 0.9;
}
/* Edited Style */
#nav-right>.active > a, #nav-right>.open>a{
background-image:none;
background-color: #428BCA;
color: white;
}
/* Edited style ends */
#nav-right>.active>li>a, #nav-right>.active>li>a:hover, #nav-right>.active>li>a :focus{
background-image:none;
background-color: #428BCA;
color: white;
}
#nav-right li a {
color: #428BCA;
}
#nav-right li a:hover{
background-color: #428BCA;
color: white;
}
#drop-menu > .active > a, #drop-menu > .active > a:hover, #drop-menu> .active > a:focus {
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #17AA76, #149466);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
#drop-menu li a:hover {
background-image:none;
background-color:#16A170;
}
#drop-menu li a{
background-image:none;
color: black;
}
```

Comment: Hi Nishant! Your solution is working but this also changes the background color of my active dropdown menu links. The CSS code, that I wrote for those dropdown links fails.

Comment: You have to style the class `#nav-right>.open>a` also. The open class is added in case the dropdown menu is opened in the nav links. Edited the answer so that you can test it.

Comment: Moreover, when I hover on the dropdown link, it abides by the CSS code of dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

Change in your bootstrap style as

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .open > a{

    /* background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #080808 0px, #0f0f0f 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset; */
    color: #fff !important; 
    background: #428bca;
}
```

Comment: Hi Anubhav! Your solution is working but this also changes the background color of my active dropdown menu links. The CSS code, that I wrote for those dropdown links fails.

Answer (score 0):

please apply this code on your solution

```
li.active a{
   background: #428BCA!important;
   color:#fff!important;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Santosh! Your solution is working but this also changes the background color of all my dropdown menu links at once. The CSS code, that I wrote for those dropdown links fails.

Comment: I even tried adding '!important' to the dropdown link CSS, but it did not work.

Comment: Put any custom class or ID in ul     .custom-class li.active a{ code}

Comment: Custom Id already there. No effect of it on dropdown menu items

Comment: Moreover, when I hover on the dropdown link, it abides by the CSS code of dropdown menu

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `important!` It's just bad css practice.
Instead add this:

```
#nav-right li.active a {
    background: #428BCA;
    color: white; }
```

PS: More on why not to use `!important`:
[What are the implications of using "!important" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)

Comment: Hello Underfrog. Your solution is working but this also changes the background color of my active dropdown menu links. The CSS code, that I wrote for those dropdown links fails.